# Is there a way to map strings to types in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, types, dart

I'd like to keep a constant map of strings to defined classes that all inherit from a single class A:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}

const strToType = {
  'str1': B,
  'str2': C,
  'str3': C,
  'str4': D,
  // etc.
};
```

Therefore, I assume that this map takes the form of `Map<String, Type>`, which I even tried explicitly stating: `<String, Type>{ /*...*/ }`

Still, I can't use this map to dynamically decide which object to create, like I would in some other languages like Python:

```
A variable = new strToType[someString](args);
```

In this case, Dart checker shows an error that `strToType is not a class`.

I tried wrapping `strToType[someString]` in parentheses, then it would complain about the `new (` part.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm doing in Dart? I'd like to avoid huge switch statements and code duplication, as `B`, `C`, `D` have the same construction inteface and there's a lot more than just 3 classes.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, in my case the string identifier of the class will only be known at runtime, I will receive a stream of strings and based on that I want to create a `List<A>`, where the elements are the specialized descendants of `A`.

Comment: What do you want to ultimately obtain with a map between strings and types? Isn't regular inheritance/polymorphism sufficient?

Comment: @nbro after I establish the inheritance chain, I'd like to decide at runtime which of the descendants I will use for data processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart `Type` objects are opaque tokens representing the type. They are not the type itself.
You cannot use a `Type` object where a class is needed, so you can't do `new TypeVar()` or `TypeVar.staticMember`.

if you want to store a way to create objects of a sub-class, you need to store a function doing that.

```
const strToType = <String, A Function(argTypes)> {
 'str1': (args) => new A(args),
 'str2': (args) => new C(args),
 'str3': (args) => new C(args),
 'str4': (args) => new D(args),
 // etc.
};
```

Then you can use it as you requested:

```
A variable = strToType[someString](args);
```

as long as all the constructors accept the same arguments.